# Electrons flowing through a circuit make it warm, where does that heat come from

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity

in a circuit I have a low resistance device that consumes many watts, in normal operation this device will get warm; where does this heat come from?

the law of conservation of energy states that the total energy of an isolated system remains constant<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy)</sup>

in this scenario, no electrons should be leaking from the circuit; and the number of electrons that enter the circuit (-) should be equal the the number of electrons that exit the circuit (+), am I correct?

If the above is true, where does the heat energy come from?

Comment: When electrons collide with the positive ions in the solid, those electrons' kinetic energy transfers to vibrational energy of those ions. Vibrating atoms in the solid is, more or less, what you mean by "heat".

Answer (score 1):

Each material has some internal resistance, so moving electrons collide with other electrons and release energy in form of heat.

[Read more](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/2000-11/973264612.Ph.r.html)

Comment: Heat is not a form of energy; it is the transfer of energy from one object to another due to a temperature difference between them, and the process you mention is not an example of that. You mean thermal (or internal) energy is increased due to the collisions.

Answer (score 1):

> in this scenario, no electrons should be leaking from the circuit; and the number of electrons that enter the circuit (-) should be equal the the number of electrons that exit the circuit (+), am I correct?

Energy conservation is not the same as charge conservation. The energy that electrons carry is determined by the circuit, an average drift velocity, which depends on the  heat energy loss in the resistive part.

> where does the heat energy come from?

Energy in a resistive electric circuit is supplied by the [EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force) , the power source. This becomes kinetic energy of the electrons , which interact in the resistive part of the circuit with the molecules of the solid, the energy becoming vibrational and rotational levels and then heat.  Energy is only conserved  if the heat generated by the system is added into the energy balance.

This is usually not the case for electrical devices which almost always generate more heat than they can store internally before reaching the destructive temperature limit. It is therefor necessary to treat most practical electric circuits as closed for charge but thermodynamically open for heat.

(This answer has been greatly improved by anna_v. Thanks for the suggestions and changes.)

Comment: you need to include in the first line a sentence of the type :"energy in a resistive electric circuit is supplied by the battery  and is only conserved ..." to have a complete answer

Comment: @annav: I was considering it but then one would have to discuss the other storage elements (capacitors and inductors) and it just seemed to make the answer messy, so I omitted it. I agree, as written it's somewhat sloppy. Please feel free to edit it to your liking.

Comment: OK, better than writing another answer

Comment: did it. of course you can roll back

Comment: @annav: I appreciate your suggestion. It's much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Energy is carried as Kinetic energy by electrons from which useful KE comes from Electric Field.
Electrons are under acceleration due to Electric Field in wire.
When millions of accelerating electrons collide with other ellectons they increase average KE of electrons which increase temperature of wire.
Electrons entering wire leave wire equally, without any increase in speed which should have been given by energy of electric field. 
This was because energy  as heat was obtained by slowing electrons and not eating them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the concept of drift velocity, on the average no. of electrons travelling in any direction will be equal to no. of electrons travelling in the opposite direction.
[image: Microscopic view of conductor]
As the electron accelerate, they frequently collide with positive metal ions or other electrons of metal.Between 2 successive collisions an electron gains  a velocity component(in addition to its random velocity)in a direction opposite to electric field.With this added velocity electron impart its energy to neighboring electrons which in turn increases the motion of charge carriers.

Also Heat energy is not the state variable it is the energy which exists during transition,hence during the motion(thermal motion) of charge carriers the energy is imparted which is heat energy.